# setTimeout logic is not invoked

Tags: javascript

Could you please help me to understand why this setTimeout logic is not working

The task is simple, when a user clicks a button a function will be executed copying the text of an input and then will print a message explaining that the copy was successful, followed that should wait a second and hide the message. This last part does not work.

I share a stack snippet

```js
(function() {
    const copyText = document.querySelector('#email');
    const copyButton = document.querySelector('#copy');
    const messageBox = document.querySelector('#message');

    function copy() {
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand('Copy');

        displayMessage();
    }

    function displayMessage() {
        messageBox.innerHTML = 'Email copied';

        clearMessage();
    }

    function clearMessage() {
        const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
            messageBox.innerHTML = '';
        }, 1000);

        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }

    copyButton.addEventListener('click', copy);
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" value="some.user@domain.com">
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<span id="message"></span>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just a note, clearTimeout is very rarely needed.  clearInterval's are more common..   clearTimeout doesn't save you any memory, it's just there to cancel a timeout, so if your always wanting to wait 1 second, clearTimeout is pointless.

Comment: Yes. You are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're immediately clearing the timeout after you set it with `window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);`. Just remove `window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);` and it will work.

There's no need to use `clearTimeout` unless you want to cancel the timeout and keep its callback from being called.

Answer (score 1):

Clear you timeout inside the function as-

```
function clearMessage() {
        const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
            messageBox.innerHTML = '';
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID); // place it here
        }, 1000);

    }
```

So, after one second, your unnecessary timeout will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks Fazal for the information, I was about to ask where it would be appropriate to put cleartimeout

Comment: you are welcome. And its a good practice to GC unnecessary timer to free up memory.

Answer (score 1):

You clear the timer straight after declaring it. Remove the window.clearTimeout() call and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);` at the end of your timeout function because setTimeout is async

```js
(function() {
    const copyText = document.querySelector('#email');
    const copyButton = document.querySelector('#copy');
    const messageBox = document.querySelector('#message');

    function copy() {
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand('Copy');

        displayMessage();
    }

    function displayMessage() {
        messageBox.innerHTML = 'Email copied';

        clearMessage();
    }

    function clearMessage() {
        const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
            messageBox.innerHTML = '';
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }, 1000);

        
    }

    copyButton.addEventListener('click', copy);
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" value="some.user@domain.com">
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<span id="message"></span>
```